# University data aggregation

Tags: web-scraping

I have a client who wants to build a web application targeted towards college students. They want the students to be able to pick which class they're in from a valid list of classes and teachers. Websites like [koofers](https://www.koofers.com), [schedulizer](http://www.schedulizer.com/#welcome), and [noteswap](http://www.noteswap.com/) all have accurate lists from many universities which are accurate year by year.

How do these companies aggregate this data? Do these universities have some api for this specific purpose?  Or, do these companies pay students from these universities to input this data every year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've done some of this for a client, and in each case we had to scrape the data.  If you can get an API definitely use it, but my guess is that the vast majority will need to be scraped.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that these companies have some kind of agreements and use an API for data exchange. If you don't have access to that API though you can still build a simple webscraper that extracts that data for you.